# Корректно ли работает php spreadsheet?

Tags: php

Никто не в курсе, корректно ли работает библиотека [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) с 30 000 строками в `excel` файле?
Например, библиотека `PHPexcel` при обработке 9 000 строк отваливалась с ошибкой `php`: типа не хватает памяти allowed memory....

Comment: Ну так а кто мешает попробовать? Кстати, в PHP есть настройка задающая лимит по памяти - его можно увеличить.

Comment: Пользуюсь год, всё устраивает

Comment: Судя по тому, что PHPExcel перенесен в архивные, изучайте новую либу)

Answer (score 0):

Нет. У меня чтение данных из большого xlsx файла(>5000 строк) выдаёт ошибку:
Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 73728 bytes) (0)
.../vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Worksheet/Worksheet.php:2540

Решил разделить файл на части.
Для этого создал фильтр и получил общее количество строк:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\IReadFilter;


class XlsxReadFilter implements IReadFilter {
    /** @var int|null $startRow */
    private $startRow;
    /** @var int|null $endRow */
    private $endRow;
    /** @var array|null $columns */
    private $columns;

    /**
     * XlsxReadFilter constructor.
     * @param int|null $startRow
     * @param int|null $endRow
     * @param array|null $columns
     */
    public function __construct(?int $startRow = null, ?int $endRow = null, ?array $columns = null) {
        $this->startRow = $startRow;
        $this->endRow = $endRow;
        $this->columns = $columns;
    }

    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = ''): bool {
        if (is_null($this->startRow) || is_null($this->endRow)) {
            return true;
        }
        if ($row >= $this->startRow && $row <= $this->endRow) {
            if (is_null($this->columns)) {
                return true;
            }
            if (in_array($column, $this->columns)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

$reader = IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');
$reader->setReadFilter(new XlsxReadFilter(null, null, array('A')));
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
/** @var string $fileFullPath */
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($fileFullPath);
$dataRowCount = (int)$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataRow();
```